# Metal vs. masonry paint for a matte paint finish on flat aluminium sheets?

Tags: painting, finishing, aluminum

I have powder-coated aluminium sheets that I'd like to paint, such that the finish looks matte, like a normal wall (i.e. no gloss).

I concluded that simply sanding the powdercoating layer a bit, to roughen it up, is enough to apply the new paint.  I.e. no need to apply a primer.

I've done some rolls of metal paints on sheets of testing metals, and I notieced some gloss even when the paint is marketed as "matte".

My questions are:

- What makes masonry paints appear as much more matte?
- What are the good ways to achieve a masonry-like matte finish on my powder-coated aluminium sheet? (long lasting, cheap paint and cheap maintenance).

Comment: @SolarMike - Maybe I'm abusing the word "matte" here?  I basically mean non-gloss, or non-reflective.

Comment: perhaps it is mason v masonry?

Comment: "The colour must be..." what?? What determines what a "masonry-like matte finish" is? How does that differ from a "regular matte finish"?

Comment: @FreeMan - Typo (colour must be).  Masonry-like matte is a bit rough.

Comment: AIUI, a matte finish is rough, but on a very small scale, so the reflections go off in all different directions and it doesn't appear "shiny". If you want it to be _visually_ and tactilely rough, like a painted brick or CMU, I'd think you'd have to put some sort of physical coating on it first, then apply the final paint coal. Or, perhaps, paint it with a roller that will leave some texture behind.

Comment: @FreeMan - Is the roller paint type suitable for outdoor use?

Comment: I would think that you can buy a pint/liter/quart/gallon of paint that's suitable for both metal and exterior use. You'd have to ask at your local paint store. I'd suggest a paint store, not a big-box DIY store - they should have more stock & more knowledge (on average).

Comment: I don't understand the question. Flat/matte sheen is the same for any kind of paint, generally speaking.

Comment: Also, "long lasting" and "cheap" don't usually correspond.